# hue installation - make apps - failed

Tags: hadoop, hue, ambari, hdp

I am following this guide for installing HUE on HDP 3.1.4 , centos 7

https://gethue.com/configure-ambari-hdp-with-hue/

at building : sudo make apps ,it fails with  :

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "webpack"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! gethue@4.7.9 webpack: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gethue@4.7.9 webpack script 'webpack --config webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the gethue package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --config webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs gethue
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls gethue
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/kosmin/hue/npm-debug.log
make[1]: *** [npm-install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kosmin/hue'
make: *** [apps] Error 2
```

any idea , what I've missed?
dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You node version seems to be:

node v6.17.1

And you need at least v10:

```
node -v
v10.19.0
```

https://docs.gethue.com/developer/development/#dependencies

(Will make it clearer in the docs https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/installation/dependencies/)

Answer (score 1):

in installed the latest versions
from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
and it is working:

centos 7:

```sh
$ npm --version
6.14.7

$ node --version
v14.7.0
```